# OEM Partners - Orders Platform permission set license

Tags: oem

We are building an SFDC OEM app. We are planning to use "Products & Price Books" with Salesforce Platform licenses for some of the Salesforce users. Based on Google search and this [official document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/oem_user_license_comparison.htm), 'Orders Platform permission set license' allows Force.com licenses to be extended.

I have two queries regarding this **Orders Platform permission set license**:

Question 1: Is this license available as Permission Set or we need to create Profiles using the same ?

Question 2: Does this licenses costs extra $$$/money for OEM partners?

Comment: Not sure but tend to think anything with the word license in it from SF is not free

Comment: Agreed - thats my gut feel as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer #1 Permission set licenses augment existing Salesforce licenses, via Setup > Users > Any User Detail page, you can associate these permission set licenses as shown below:

[image]

On next screen select the "Orders Platform" license, as shown below:

[image]

Answer #2 Talked to my India based AE, he said no extra cost of this permission set license, more details here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/oem_user_license_comparison.htm